# How to check if a custom user profile field is empty

Tags: customization

i have this code to limit the comments per user.

```
<!-- #only one comment -->
<?php global $current_user,$post;
$usercomment = get_comments(array('author_email' => $current_user->user_email, 'post_id' => $post->ID));
if($usercomment) {
    echo "Thank you!";
}
else {
    comment_form();
}
 ?>
```

How can edit this code to also check if a custom user profile field [phone] is empty? If is empty display a message else display the comment form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the user meta for the key you want:

```
if ( get_user_meta('phone') !='' ) { 
echo "Your phone is not set";
}

else {
comment_form();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_author_meta( 'customfield' )` should give you the information that you can use in your conditional. Assuming *customfield* would be replaced by *phone* or whatever your custom field is named.